# Process exited with code 5100 while installing ClickOnce setup built in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, clickonce, 32bit-64bit, .net-4.5

[Similar thread,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158331/error-code-5100-when-installing-net-framework-as-part-of-a-clickonce-app-deploy)

I am using Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64-bit OS. I have created a deployment project with prerequisite as .NET framework 4.5.1 in Visual Studio 2013 professional.

If I launch the .net framework setup separately then I don't observe any problem and it installs properly.

When I launch setup.exe,
 - It first shows the EULA screen, I hit ACCEPT button
 - It shows Installing progress for .NET framework 4.5.1 (it prompts me to allow permission elevation)
 - Suddenly it shows below error and stops.

[image]

The log file snap looks like below,

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = SameSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 1 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.1.0 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Release' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'DotNet45Full_Release'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 (x86 and x64)':
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX451\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'DotNet45Full_Release' was not defined
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionNT' and value '6.3.0': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '6.0.0': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64': false
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX451\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' is 'Install'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX451\NDP451-KB2859818-Web.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX451\NDP451-KB2859818-Web.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
EULA for components 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 (x86 and x64)' was accepted.
Copying files to temporary directory "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDA8FB.tmp\"
Copying from 'C:\Users\user001\Desktop\NET framework\Products\Release\DotNetFX451\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' to 'C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDA8FB.tmp\DotNetFX451\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe'
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDA8FB.tmp\DotNetFX451\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 (x86 and x64)', phase BeforePackage
Reading value 'Release' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'DotNet45Full_Release'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 (x86 and x64)':
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX451\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'DotNet45Full_Release' was not defined
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionNT' and value '6.3.0': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '6.0.0': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64': false
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX451\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' is 'Install'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDA8FB.tmp\DotNetFX451\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
Installing using command 'C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDA8FB.tmp\DotNetFX451\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' and parameters ' /q /norestart /ChainingPackage FullX64Bootstrapper'
Process exited with code 5100
Status of package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 (x86 and x64)' after install is 'InstallFailed'
```

I don't know what problem it is hitting. Any help in resolving this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out that the setup.exe was running in compatibility mode and it was blocking .net framework.

I checked the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX451\Product.xml file and removed the Agrument attribute values just to check what error it is throwing. It threw

Blocking Issue
.NET Framework Setup cannot be run in Program Compatibility Mode.

I removed this compatibility settings from setup.exe and it works fine now.